# using relative dates in select query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to use relative dates in my query. From searching I've seen two ways of doing this (sure there are more) but neither work for me and I can see data in my table for 2016-06-14

```
select * from tblMy where DatePrice = GETDATE() - 1

select * from tblMy where DatePrice = DATEADD(DAY, -1, GETDATE())
```

Comment: What is datatype of the column "DatePrice" ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because `GETDATE()` (despite its name) has a time component.  So, if `DatePrice` does not have a time component, they match only at exactly midnight.  If `DatePrice` does have a time component, then they will almost never match.

You can use:

```
where DatePrice = CAST(DATEADD(DAY, -1, GETDATE()) as DATE)
```

Or, in a version safe with or without time components:

```
where DatePrice >= CAST(DATEADD(DAY, -1, GETDATE()) as DATE) AND
      DatePrice < CAST(GETDATE() as DATE)
```

Comment: ah that makes sense! The table I was looking at just has a date without the time component